# Qt/QML, MacOS и ретина дисплей

Tags: c++, qt, macos, qml, retina

Пытаюсь проверить, как будет работать программа с ретина дисплеем. У меня MacOS установлен на виртуальной машине VMware Workstation. Я установил размер монитора в 3840x2160, а в настройках самой MacOS выбрал 1920x1080 с молнией(это hidpi, да?). В общем если сделать скриншот рабочего стола, то он будет в 3840x2160. В программе же, если выводить в лог размер окна, то оно будет в два раза меньше. Видимо так работает поддержка hidpi.

Что бы отключить это, я пробовал все что удалось загуглить:

- устанавливать AA_DisableHighDpiScaling/AA_EnableHighDpiScaling
- устанавливать QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR в 0/1,
  QT_ENABLE_HIGHDPI_SCALING и QT_SCALE_FACTOR
- в файле Info.plist устанавливать NSHighResolutionCapable и
  NSPrincipalClass

И перезагружал виртуалку после каждого изменения. И всё-равно при запуске программа видит не то разрешение, что я ожидал(а ожидал я то разрешение, что я вижу при скриншоте - 3840x2160).

Вопросы:

1. Должна ли программа увидеть 3840x2160?
2. Можно ли вообще проверить на виртуалке работу с ретина дисплеем?